# How render table from ajax with unknown number of columns

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have webapi that return a datatable 
in the success function of ajax i would create a template string in javascript to render table

problem is column are not fixed
i can have for example

Line, 2000, 2001
or
Line, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003

the table is a pivot that sum sales by product line and year

how can i know number of each element in array?

Comment: So are you just looking to get `array.length;` ?

Comment: I see array length in console. Problem is the table should render different number of columns for different customers. so how can i create a template table checking the result of success: function(result)?

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite vague, but to answer "how can i know number of each element in array", use `length`.

So, for instance:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
var myArrayLength = myArray.length
console.log(myArrayLength); // Will be 5
```

Comment: No i have function GetSalesByCustomerAndYear(customerCode) that return a pivot table. I have sometimes 3 coumns or 15 based on customer sales. In my promise of ajax i want create a 'run time' table. But i do not know how many year in the column i get: 2000, 2001   or from 2000 and 2018

Answer (score 0):

my array might be contains
{
2004
:
null
2005
:
null
2006
:
8914.61
2007
:
10280.5
2008
:
8139.5
2009
:
16384
2010
:
17510.5
2011
:
23016
2012
:
23391.5
2013
:
18231
2014
:
19378
2015
:
13308
2016
:
22208.830000000093
2017
:
25174.180000000073
2018
:
4494.84
linea
:
"PL1"
}

or can be

{
2012
:
23391.5
2013
:
18231
2014
:
19378
2015
:
13308
2016
:
22208.830000000093
2017
:
25174.180000000073
2018
:
4494.84
linea
:
"PL1"
}